# SPList instance members throw a NullReferenceException

Tags: sharepoint, design-patterns, nullreferenceexception, splist

To cut a long story real short... I have a class (in my sample scenario it's a application page) which holds a reference to a SPList.

```
public partial class ApplicationPage1 : LayoutsPageBase
{
    private static SPList _list = GetSPList();

    private static SPList GetSPList()
    {
        try
        {
            return SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("/Lists/CoreConfiguration");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void BtnRunQuery_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(_list.Author.Name);
    }
}
```

The interesting part is the button click event obviously. Because the first time it *always* works. And maybe if you are lucky it works a 2nd or a 3rd time. But it almost never works a 4th time at which point it throws a NullReferenceException. It's not the list itself which throws the exception but rather some members of the class. Obviously the SPList object is more dead than alive.

So apparently it's not a good idea to hold a reference to a SPList.
Is the design pattern to follow here to go and get the list each and every time? On each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the very best idea to hold an `SPList` instance in a `static` field. In fact, you may not do that. As `SPContext.Current`'s name indicates, it the *current* context in the very specific point in time. To put it short (and simplified), it's request-specific, and a `SPList` instance is as well.

You have to retrieve a new `SPList` instance every time you need it. Internally, it's bound to `SPWeb` instance, for which it's the same—it cannot survive among requests. The rule of thumb here is: how would you distinguish among different users' permission should you have just one static `SPList` instance?

---

Side note: The reason why it worked for the 1st request is plain simple: You class gets initialized by the CLR when it's first used, which is apparently during the first request. The CRL then invokes the class'es static constructor, which computes values of static members, and since `SPContext.Current` is valid at that time, it seams to work.

Comment: The static variable was just to proof my point :) In reality it's an IoC container controlled object of request-indepenent lifetime. And if we were talking about 1000 concurrent users... that would be 1000 SPList objects? I want the whole content and always up to date (no intermediary caching) and no security trimming.

Comment: Yes, if it's 1000 concurrent users, you'll end up with 1000 `SPList` instances. Nothing much to worry about. Don't optimize unless it's a real problem. I think caching should be appropriate here; I don't think your list will change 1000-times per second (because that's hardly achievable in SharePoint…), so maybe you could be safe with checking `SPList.LastItemModifiedDate`, say, every second. And if you don't want any security trimming, you will have to elevate privileges anyway.